# Moveit: Interactive markers missing

Tags: ros, moveit, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am fairly new to the using Moveit (as well as ROS overall), and did the tutorial on using the setup assistant for moveit. moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Setup_Assistant/Quick_Start.

After successfully creating the package at the end, I then went on to run the demo.launch file that was created after creating moveit package. RVIZ came up successfully with the PR2 robot model showing. However I am unable to use the interactive markers to control the planning groups because there are no interactive markers showing. Can anyone help me understand why the interactive markers are missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115641/moveit:-interactive-markers-missing/) by [mfran89](https://answers.ros.org/users/10546/mfran89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-01-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look at this:
http://answers.ros.org/question/114936/interact-button-in-moveitrviz-plugin/
I think you have the same problem. Check your end effector.

---

Originally posted by [Fred](https://answers.ros.org/users/10581/fred/) with karma: 26 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mfran89](https://answers.ros.org/users/10546/mfran89/) on 2014-01-08**:
In the tutorial that I pointed out in my original question, step 8 asks to label the end effectors. I took this as defining the end effectors. So my problem still exists after the fact that I have defined my end effectors. Thank you for your suggestion.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-10-18**:
I added a comment in the link above; in my case the parent group for the `eef` definition was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There can be multiple reasons the interactive marker fails to load

### Possibility 1: kinematics solver not set up correctly

In order for the interactive marker to appear, the group must have a kinematic solver attached to it.

Check your `kinematics.yaml` to make sure you've specified the correct group name and kinematic solver AND check log outputs to make sure there were no errors when loading the kinematic solver

If you see the following line

```
[kinematics_plugin_loader]: The kinematics plugin (your group name) failed to load.
```

you are very likely to get the `No active joints or end effectors found for group` error (which also directly leads to the missing interactive marker)

[ref](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/616#issuecomment-1111330465)

### Possibility 2: Something causing MoveIt rviz plugin to not "find" the interactive marker server

Click "Add" in the rviz display panel, select "By Topic" and add the topic `/rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic/update` topic which should be of type `InteractiveMarkers`.  The `InteractiveMarker` that gets added will still work correctly with the MoveIt rviz plugin

### Possibility 3: Issues with FastDDS (seems more prominent in docker containers)

Try switching to CycloneDDS by following [these instructions](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/DDS-Implementations/Working-with-Eclipse-CycloneDDS.html)

###Ref:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/402780/ros2humble-async_send_request-service-result-seldomly-never-returns-using-executors/
- https://discourse.ros.org/t/fastdds-without-discovery-server/26117/13
- https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/issues/628

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2022-04-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hector.herrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/18916/hector.herrero/) on 2022-05-10**:
This was my case, the group defined in `kinematics.yaml` was not correct.